# Problem with card responsiveness on different devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I have a little problem and I wanted to ask if anyone had encountered a similar problem and managed to solve it. The problem is the responsiveness on mobile devices, when I use the resolution of the mobile device, the text and the photo are overlapping each other. Anyone have an idea how to solve it?

```css
.card_new {
  background: var(--accent);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card_new_img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 270px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.bottom-10px {
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://devilweb.pl/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://devilweb.pl/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-xxl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-xl-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-xl-6 py-3">
          <div class="card_new position-relative">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6 pr-0">
                <img src="https://waskiel.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/jak-zrobic-dobre-zdjecie-ustawienia-aparatu.jpg" class="w-100 card_new_img">
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 position-relative">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-6">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-3 text-right">
                        <span class="material-icons-outlined font-size-two-rem color-second-page">
                            favorite_border
                        </span>
                        <p class="color-second-page">
                          210
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-3">
                        <span class="material-icons-outlined font-size-two-rem color-second-page">
                            heart_broken
                        </span>
                        <p class="color-second-page">
                          007
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 text-center child">
                    <h3 class="font-weight-bold">
                      Photo&Art
                    </h3>
                    Agnieszka Malczak
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 position-absolute bottom-10px">
                    <center>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary rounded" type="submit">
                          Zobacz więcej
                      </button>
                    </center>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <img src="https://patrzszerzej.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/IMG_0160cnet.jpg" class="card_new_img child" style="width:125px;height:125px;border-radius: 100%;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The photo below is from Full HD resolution: https://prnt.sc/XCqaaQpSTuWF Everything is fine here, but when the resolution is reduced, something like this happens: https://prnt.sc/AtI2k-uN56AP

So, my question is boring, does anyone have an idea at least or can suggest how to solve it?

Comment: Please revise to post photos using the editor, not links to photo _pages_.

Comment: Responsive behavior often involves translating from rows to columns for mobile. Without knowing what design you'd find acceptable this question is too broad. I suggest that you look at how other websites handle similar situations, work up a design concept, and make an attempt, then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. We're not a discussion forum.

Answer (score -1):

This is more of a design question but some options...

using a media query, you could: hide the photo on a smaller size, hide the bg landscape on size or both.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Answers on SO are expected to be more specific. Please see [answer].

Comment: Also, you'll find that most developers consider [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to be a more canonical resource. While W3S is a useful resource, it has had problems.